# Bottom Bracket Press fit to a square taper

Tags: road-bike, bottom-bracket, crankset

I like to use my old Campagnolo crank on a new road bike frame. The frame has already a Pressfit BB71-41A installed. The crank needs a sqaure tape. Is it possible to use the crank with a adapter or do I need to buy a new frame/crank.

Bike Frame: used Bulls Desert Falcon Pro
Crank: Campagnolo Racing T 9 Speed

Comment: You can't. Either get a new frame which supports a traditional BB or buy a new crank.

Comment: would a new athena 11 speed crank be compatible with my 9 speed chorus/racing t parts?

Comment: I believe not, but I don't do Campy. You'd still need a new frame to put an Ultra Torque crankset on there though, anyway, iirc.

Comment: Athena 11s is Power Torque and there is an adapter from BB86 to Power Torque from Campagnolo.
http://www.amazon.com/Campagnolo-Power-Torque-BB86-Adapter/dp/B008H60V9E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say no. If the frame had a screw-in BB shell you could simply fit a tapered axle and bearings. Looks like you'll need a new chainset (that comes complete with axle) - however you could get rid of the cheapo BB71-41A (MTB type - why would anybody fit this?) and fit whatever bearings suit the chainset of your choice